# Bug: ion-spinner has memory leak

Tags: ionic-framework

**Platform**: All(Android/ios/Windows etc..)

**Problem 1:**

The current implementation does not cleanup on the deletion of the scope. This leads to a memory leak. The spinning animation keeps on running even if the spinner is not in the dom anymore. The animation should be stopped when the scope gets destroyed. This degrades scrolling performance too.

Once they have been displayed and then hidden again they still remain in the DOM animating and eat up CPU. After a while on Android devices it heats the phone up and runs the battery down very quickly, especially if you have loaded the animated SVG in multiple views / places while using the app.

**Problem 2:**

The spinner in combination with the infinite-scroll directive.
[image]

It is not sufficient to have the spinner translated out of view. (Why this solution was chosen instead of opacity?). The spinner is still getting animated and degrades scrolling performance on iOS devices a lot. Even if out of view.

Comment: Memory leak is a resource disposal control problem, not performance problem You did not provide actual evidence of memory "leaked" (in numbers), and you can't do this without debugger and source. It's unclear what's asked.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report more than anything. Can you please take it over to Github and post it as an issue for the Ionic team to respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply replaced the SVG spinner with a .gif loader:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
   template: "<span class='loader'></span>"
});
```

Not the best solution but at least it works.